# getLastKnownLocation() returns null using GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps

I'm making a little test program to get the hang of Android GPS, and see how the battery is effected for a school project. I simply want my device to detect my location by printing out the latitude of the last known location detected. But the location always returns null in the onResume() callback.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
TextView Updates;
long start = -1;
long battStart = -1;
long stop = -1;
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
LocationManager locationManager; 
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Updates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Updates.append("\n onCreate()");

    batteryLevel();
    start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
          Updates.append("\n Found a place! "+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude());
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Updates.append("yes"+provider);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Updates.append("No"+provider);
        }
    }; 
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Updates.append("\n onStart()");

    // Set up a wake lock 
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    this.wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag2");
    this.wl.acquire();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    batteryLevel();
    Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (loc != null) {
        Updates.append(String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
    } else {
        Updates.append("loc is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

Turns out, I just had to go outside :)

Answer (score 1):

If GPS is disabled, it will always return null. Refer to the Android docs for [LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should use LocationListener. because it may happen you may not get location from getLastKnownLocation().

just  call requestLocationUpdates you 'll get the callback in LocationListener